# Meteor-slingshot - File upload to AWS S3 pending, then failing with 400 Bad request on random occasions

Tags: meteor, file-upload, amazon-s3, image-uploading, meteor-slingshot

I'm trying to upload an image to AWS S3 in Meteor/Slingshot. The upload is pending for a long time and then failing (400 Bad request). Some files managed to upload but most of the time they don't. This seems to be happening randomly.

What are the reasons that may cause this?

The S3 bucket is in Ireland "eu-west-1". Here's the code I have:

**In settings.json:**

```
{
  "public": {

  },
  "AWSAccessKeyId" : <keyID>,
  "AWSSecretAccessKey" : <Secret>,
  "AWSBucket" : <bucket_name>,
  "AWSRegion": "eu-west-1"
}
```

**app/lib/_fileUploadRestrictions.js**

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions("imageUploads", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB (use null for unlimited).
});
```

**app/server/fileUploadDirectives.js**

```
Slingshot.createDirective("imageUploads", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  region: Meteor.settings.AWSRegion,
  bucket: Meteor.settings.AWSBucket,
  acl: "public-read",
  expire: 200,

  authorize: function () {
    //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.
    if (!this.userId) {
      var message = "Please login before posting files";
      throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
    }

    return true;
  },

  key: function (file) {
    //Store file into a directory by the user's username.
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    return "userfilies" + "/" + userId + "/" + "images" + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

**app/client/fileUploader.js**

```
Template.fileUploader.events({
  'change .fileinput': function(event, template) {
    var fileToUpload = event.target.files[0];
    var fullUpload = new Slingshot.Upload("imageUploads");
    fullUpload.send(fileToUpload, function (error, downloadUrl) {
      if (error) {
        toastr.error("Upload failed... please try again.");
        console.log(error);
        console.log(fullUpload.xhr.response);
      }
      else {
        toastr.success('Upload succeeded!');
      }
    });
    Template.instance().uploader.set(fullUpload);
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: No I didn't. I've read somewhere that S3 doesn't play well if the files are uploaded from a different region but I didn't investigate any further. If that's true then you'll have to upload the images to your app server first and make sure it is on the same region. Which makes using slingshot pointless. Anyway, I ended up using cloudinary for image uploads which takes care of everything, including CDN.

Comment: K thnk for your relpy.